# Using Google Maps API to get Address of Business

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a requirement and I am hoping Google Maps API will have a solution. I have never used Google Maps API - so I am very new to this.

On the website homepage there is a form, when a user comes, I want the following things to happen:

1) The city field should be populated with users city based on IP

2) There is a second field called store name - when the user starts typing the store name - I want to fetch all business listings with that name in that city and show it as a drop down from which the user can select the appropriate branch. There is no need for anything to be shown on the map.
Egs - If a user in houston starts typing McDonalds, the following business listings should start showing up

- McDonalds, 12 Pearland Ave, Houston TX
- McDonalds, 2600 Bary Area Blvd, Houston TX
- McDonalds, 262 Clearlake Blvd, Houston TX

Also when we get the address for a business listing from Google API - do we get it as one String and we need to parse it or do we get it different fields Street Name, City, State, Zip code etc

Any information or examples will be really appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I added a sample using both client location and local search to fetch businesses local to the client for reference by yourself and others that come looking for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think you want Google Maps. First of all the terms of use do not allow any use other than displaying things on a Google Map on a publicly accessible webpage, second, there is another Google API that does exactly what you need: the Client location API: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#ClientLocation

Concerning the "businesses": You're going to have to source that data from somewhere - I do not believe google has a service for that. Perhaps  you could simply use the Google Search API and some logic to find only businesses (http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/)

EDIT: I for the businesses, perhaps you could take a look at this sample: [http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/samples.html#*local-search*](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/samples.html#_local-search_)

Comment: Hello Roland
Thanks for your response - When I mean business - I am talking about businesses that already show up on google local search. For example if you go to http://maps.google.co.in/ and search McDonalds Houston - it will show you the following results:
2017 Main Street, Houston, TX, United States‎
808 Dallas Street, Houston, TX, United States
4005 Elgin Street, Houston, TX, United States

So we cannot get this information from Google if I pass "MCdonalds" and "Houston".

Thanks

Comment: Oops - I'm sorry I did'nt see your Edit Note 
Looking at it now.

Comment: So I can use 
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#center_localsearch
It does not show it on the map and it gives me the business addresses.
Is there any terms that state that I cant use it for purposes other than showing on the Maps.
Thanks

Comment: well, as long as you're not using the google maps api, you are. The apis I mentioned are not the google maps api. Of course, you should follow the links I provided and read any terms of use/service and see if those are compatible with your application.

Comment: It looks like these APIs and/or documentation have changed, as these links no longer work. Do you know what the best current solution is?

Comment: Any issues hitting the limit with places api? Seems easy but hate to build in something with a hard cap

Answer (score 3):

updated: here is an example of using the [google clientlocation api](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#ClientLocation) and localsearch using jsonp.

---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAALDWeTDQHOJCbCf0JnUqL8BT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxQA7AE8xB9MyWgHECPY2qimOp7BUQ"></script>

    <script src="scripts/clientLocation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="scripts/localSearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">



        function $g(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }

        function displayLocation(latitudeEl, longitudeEl, cityEl, regionEl, countryEl, country_codeEl) {
            var cloc = new ClientLocation.Location(google.loader.ClientLocation);
            if (latitudeEl) latitudeEl.innerHTML = cloc.latitude;
            if (longitudeEl) longitudeEl.innerHTML = cloc.longitude;
            if (cityEl) cityEl.innerHTML = cloc.address.city;
            if (regionEl) regionEl.innerHTML = cloc.address.region;
            if (country) country.innerHTML = cloc.address.country;
            if (country_codeEl) country_codeEl.innerHTML = cloc.address.country_code;
        }
        function localSearch(term, callback, context) {
            var cloc = new ClientLocation.Location(google.loader.ClientLocation);
            var searchUrl = 'http://www.google.com/uds/GlocalSearch?callback=' + callback + '&context=' + context + '&hl=en&q=' + encodeURIComponent(term) + '&sll=' + cloc.latitude + ',' + cloc.longitude + '&key=ABQIAAAALDWeTDQHOJCbCf0JnUqL8BT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxQA7AE8xB9MyWgHECPY2qimOp7BUQ&v=1.0';

            // http://jaybyjayfresh.com/2007/09/17/using-script-tags-to-do-remote-http-calls-in-javascript/
            scriptLoaded = function() {
                removeNode(newScript);
            };

            var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            var newScript = document.createElement('script');
            newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
            newScript.onload = scriptLoaded;
            newScript.src = searchUrl;
            headID.appendChild(newScript);
        }
        function search() {
            var term = $g("txtSearch").value;
            localSearch(term, "displayResults", "0");

        }
        function displayResults(context, results, status, details, unused) {
            var titles = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < results.results.length; i++) {
                // this cast is not necessary, just here to illustrate
                // vs intellisense and reduce coding errors.
                var result = new LocalSearch.Result(results.results[i]);
                titles.push(result.title);
            }
            $g("searchResults").innerHTML = titles.join("</br>");
        }
        function init() {

            displayLocation($g("latitude"), $g("longitude"), $g("city"), $g("region"), $g("country"), $g("country_code"));
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        latitude : <span id="latitude"></span>
        <br />
        longitude : <span id="longitude"></span>
        <br />
        city : <span id="city"></span>
        <br />
        region : <span id="region"></span>
        <br />
        country : <span id="country"></span>
        <br />
        country_code : <span id="country_code"></span>
        <br />
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="txtSearch" /><input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="get results"
        onclick="search();" /><br />
    &nbsp;<div id="searchResults">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
// <copyright file="clientLocation.js" company="Sky Sanders">
// This source is placed in the Public Domain.
// http://skysanders.net/subtext
// Attribution is appreciated.
// </copyright>


/*
object literal format for google.loader.clientlocation  
{
"latitude": 33.324,
"longitude": -111.867,
"address": {
"city": "Chandler",
"region": "AZ",
"country": "USA",
"country_code": "US"
}
}
*/

var ClientLocation = {};

ClientLocation.Address = function() {
    /// <field name="city" type="String" />
    /// <field name="region" type="String" />
    /// <field name="country" type="String" />
    /// <field name="country_code" type="String" />
    /// <returns type="ClientLocation.Address"/>
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        this.city = arguments[0].city;
        this.region = arguments[0].region;
        this.country = arguments[0].country;
        this.country_code = arguments[0].country_code;
        return;
    }
    else {
        this.city = "";
        this.region = "";
        this.country = "";
        this.country_code = "";
    }

}
ClientLocation.Location = function() {
    /// <field name="latitude" type="Number" />
    /// <field name="longitude" type="Number" />
    /// <field name="address" type="ClientLocation.Address" />
    if (arguments.length > 0) {

        this.latitude = arguments[0].latitude;
        this.longitude = arguments[0].longitude;
        this.address = arguments[0].address;

    }
    else {
        this.latitude = 0;
        this.longitude = 0;
        this.address = undefined;
    }

}


// <copyright file="localSearc.js" company="Sky Sanders">
// This source is placed in the Public Domain.
// http://skysanders.net/subtext
// Attribution is appreciated.
// </copyright>
/*
GlocalSearch result

{
"GsearchResultClass": "GlocalSearch",
"viewportmode": "computed",
"listingType": "local",
"lat": "33.389689",
"lng": "-111.853909",
"accuracy": "8",
"title": "Best \u003cb\u003eBuy\u003c/b\u003e",
"titleNoFormatting": "Best Buy",
"ddUrl": "http://www.google.com/maps....",
"ddUrlToHere": "http://www.google.com/maps?....",
"ddUrlFromHere": "http://www.google.com/maps?....",
"streetAddress": "1337 South Alma School Road",
"city": "Mesa",
"region": "AZ",
"country": "United States",
"staticMapUrl": "http://mt.google.com/mapdata?....",
"url": "http://www.google.com/maps/place?source....",
"content": "",
"maxAge": 604800,
"phoneNumbers": [{
"type": "",
"number": "(480) 644-7139"
},
{
"type": "",
"number": "(480) 464-0444"
}],
"addressLines": ["1337 South Alma School Road", "Mesa, AZ"]
}

*/


var LocalSearch = {};

LocalSearch.PhoneNumber = function() {
    /// <field name="type" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="number" type="String"/>
    /// <returns type="LocalSearch.PhoneNumber"/>

    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        this.type = arguments[0].type;
        this.number = arguments[0].number;
    }
    else {
        this.type = "";
        this.number = "";
    }
}



LocalSearch.Result = function() {
    /// <field name="GsearchResultClass" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="viewportmode" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="listingType" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="lat" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="lng" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="accuracy" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="title" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="titleNoFormatting" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="ddUrl" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="ddUrlToHere" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="ddUrlFromHere" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="streetAddress" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="city" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="region" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="country" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="staticMapUrl" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="url" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="content" type="String"/>
    /// <field name="maxAge" type="Number"/>
    /// <field name="phoneNumbers" type="Array"/>
    /// <field name="addressLines" type="Array"/>
    // <returns type="LocalSearch.Result"/>
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        this.GsearchResultClass = arguments[0].GsearchResultClass;
        this.viewportmode = arguments[0].viewportmode;
        this.listingType = arguments[0].listingType;
        this.lat = arguments[0].lat;
        this.lng = arguments[0].lng;
        this.accuracy = arguments[0].accuracy;
        this.title = arguments[0].title;
        this.titleNoFormatting = arguments[0].titleNoFormatting;
        this.ddUrl = arguments[0].ddUrl;
        this.ddUrlToHere = arguments[0].ddUrlToHere;
        this.ddUrlFromHere = arguments[0].ddUrlFromHere;
        this.streetAddress = arguments[0].streetAddress;
        this.city = arguments[0].city;
        this.region = arguments[0].region;
        this.country = arguments[0].country;
        this.staticMapUrl = arguments[0].staticMapUrl;
        this.url = arguments[0].url;
        this.content = arguments[0].content;
        this.maxAge = arguments[0].maxAge;
        this.phoneNumbers = arguments[0].phoneNumbers;
        this.addressLines = arguments[0].addressLines;

    }
    else {

        this.GsearchResultClass = "";
        this.viewportmode = "";
        this.listingType = "";
        this.lat = "";
        this.lng = "";
        this.accuracy = "";
        this.title = "";
        this.titleNoFormatting = "";
        this.ddUrl = "";
        this.ddUrlToHere = "";
        this.ddUrlFromHere = "";
        this.streetAddress = "";
        this.city = "";
        this.region = "";
        this.country = "";
        this.staticMapUrl = "";
        this.url = "";
        this.content = "";
        this.maxAge = 0;
        this.phoneNumbers = [];
        this.addressLines = [];
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code Sanders
I was basically looking for a way where the user specifies the business name and city - and using that info I can pull the address using Google code.
Roland provided me with this link which does exactly that:
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#center_localsearch
But my concern is whether I can use that information and store it in my database

Comment: yeah, i was just finishing up a sample of pulling from GLocalSearch with a simple JsonP strategy. As for storage, and usage of this sample, you will have to examine the terms of use posted on the google api page.

I posted the sample for other people who come looking for this type of thing

Comment: You need to check the Google license. I do not believe you can "scrub" their data for re-use / storage. For our map plotting we had to go the business license with them. Plus you are limited on the number of calls you can make on the free versions, but that may not impact you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only looking up restaurants, try using Yelp's API. You can search for a business by its name within a search radius. Their API is also simpler and easier to use than google's.

http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/search_api